# Sys SQL Lite DB in SQL Server Real TIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

How to real time sys sqlite database in SQL Server when any data change in sqlite database so automatically reflect in SQL Server database?

Comment: Expecting "real time" between disparate database engines without significant design / implementation experience suggests a need for hands-on help.Suggest you search the internet for "replication"

Comment: replication option not available in sqllite to sql server